# Inter-process communication with SendMessage on Windows and Qt5

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

My problem is, I suppose, reasonably common: opening a file in the first instance of my app when a second instance is run (e.g. by opening an asociated file in the explorer).

The way I implemented this on Windows is by using the `SendMessage` Win API and receiving the message by reimplementing winEvent in a Qt window. This worked well enough on Qt4. But for some reason, it stopped working completely after I had updated my app to Qt 5.

I have written a minimal test (see below) that reproduces the behaviour: also fine on Qt 4, but not working on Qt 5 (the message is not received). I am using `mingw32` (`gcc`) in case it makes any difference. I am very unfamiliar with the Windows API so would be delighted if someone could explain the odd behaviour.

Thanks a lot!

server.c:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <windef.h>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDialog>

#include "winmessagelistener.h"

bool WinMessageListener::winEvent( MSG* message, long* result ) {
    if( message->message == WM_COPYDATA ) {
        label->setText( "Message!" );
        // We process the event here
        *result = 0;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // Give the event to qt
        return false;
    }
}

WinMessageListener::WinMessageListener() : QDialog() {
    setWindowTitle( "blah" );
    label = new QLabel( this );
    label->setText("no message");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
        WinMessageListener listener;

    listener.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

winmessagelistener.h:

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>

class WinMessageListener : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        WinMessageListener();

    private:
        // Override the default event message
        bool winEvent( MSG* message, long* result );
        QLabel* label;
};
```

client.c:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <windef.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <QString>

const QString WINDOW_TITLE = "blah";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    LPCWSTR window_title = (LPCWSTR) WINDOW_TITLE.utf16();
    HWND window_handle_ = FindWindow( NULL, window_title );

    std::cerr << "Window handle = " << window_handle_ << std::endl;

    COPYDATASTRUCT data = { 0, 0, 0 };

    SendMessage( window_handle_, WM_COPYDATA, 0, (LPARAM) &data );
}
```

Comment: I think that `winEvent(MSG * message, long * result)` has been replaced by `nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)` in Qt5, that could explain why you don't receive the message

Comment: The [Q_DECL_OVERRIDE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_DECL_OVERRIDE) makro is a useful tool to avoid the kind of problem @AlexisP. points to. Note that it needs a compiler with C++11 support.

Comment: Now I feel a bit embarrassed, that was the problem indeed! I must get into the habit of always adding "override" (I use C++11) to detect this kind of problem. Thanks a lot both, feel free to write a response so I can accept it.

Comment: Also, your example is maybe Ok as long as SendMessage is the last statement in the program but in general never ever use Send but PostMessage for interprocess and even interthread communications.

Comment: I mean 'override' keyword! Facepalm. That is to always correctly overload virtual function.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, we should use the function relevant to what we are doing. PostMessage cannot work for inter-process communication because the memory is shared between the processes. Look at the [WM_COPYDATA message (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, well the documentation is not explicit now about not using PostMessage but it used to be. The problem is that since PostMessage is asynchronous the memory can be gone before the receiving process gets it. You won't find an example that works of using PostMessage to send WM_COPYDATA to another process.

Comment: @user34660 Good to know that the IPC needs the source to stay until the data send to the other process. I also want to read something on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an answer can help others better than comments, here it is. The problem is that in Qt5, the function `bool QWidget::winEvent(MSG * message, long * result)` is no longer available. It has been replaced by the function `bool QWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)`, as it is stated in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html):

> Note: This function superseedes the event filter functions x11Event(), winEvent() and macEvent() of Qt 4.

Note that in a more general way, and as @Paul R. said that in the comments, don't forget to use the macro [Q_DECL_OVERRIDE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_DECL_OVERRIDE) in order to allow the compiler to generate an error if your overriding of the virtual function does nothing. In that case, it could have been used like this :

```
bool WinMessageListener::winEvent(MSG * message, long * result) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
```

Note : this is a C++11 contextual keyword, and thus your compiler needs to support C++11 if you want to use it. If you are not using a compiler supporting C++11, you won't get any diagnostics.

Comment: [Q_DECL_OVERRIDE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_DECL_OVERRIDE) is a macro that expands to a contextual keyword only, if the compiler supports it. Your compiler doesn't have to support C++11 to use this macro. If you are using a compiler without C++11 support, you simply won't get any diagnostics.

Comment: That is what I meant but I agree that the answer is not pretty clear on this point. Will definitely edit this